# On what basis indexes are selected

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, query-optimization

I have a question: I have a clustered index on `orderid,productid` and a non-clustered index on `productid`. When I am using the following query, it uses the nonclustered index seek on `productid`, which I expected:

```
select orderid, productid 
from Sales.OrderDetails
where productid =1
order by productid
```

However, without changing the search arguments, I added the `Quantity`:

```
select orderid, productid, qty 
from Sales.OrderDetails
where productid =1
order by productid
```

Now it used a clustered index scan; and when I force use non clustered index (`productid`) the performance drops.

Comment: If the nonclustered index is only on productid, and doesn't contain orderid, it seems strange that the addition of the qty field causes use of the clustered index - either way it would require an key lookup to the clustered index.  Can you post the execution plans?

Comment: Reorder fields: `select productid, orderid, qty`.

Comment: @marc_s Good call, I've updated my comment.

Comment: The an answer is [the tipping point](http://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2013/06/12/sql-server-tipping-games-why-non-clustered-indexes-are-just-ignored/).

Answer (score 4):

Every nonclustered index will contain the clustering key in its leaf level nodes. So your nonclustered index on `productid` really contains `productid` **and** `orderid` in its leaf level nodes.

So your first query can be satisfied by just looking up the value in the nonclustered index - the leaf level node found will contain both columns that your `SELECT` requires.

This is **NOT** the case when you add another column, like `qty` - now, once found, a key lookup into the actual data page is necessary to get all the columns to be returned from your `SELECT` query. So therefore, maybe now a clustered index scan is performing better than a nonclustered index seek and a key lookup.

I'm pretty sure the second query would use the nonclustered index again once you **include** the `qty` column in your index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_productId
ON Sales.OrderDetails(productId)
INCLUDE (qty)
```

because again: now once the leaf-level page in the non-clustered index is found, all necessary columns are present on that page and can be returned to your second query.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense, when you added the qty column using the clustered index is ideal because the non index (data) columns are located near the clustered indexed attribs.

Answer (score 0):

**Index: "The right index will help optimizer finding the best execution plan"**

Selectivity: Density of an Index = 1 divided by the no of distinct records.Lower the value of density, higher the chances for Index to be choosen by optimizer, there by higher SELECTIVITY. For every Index, there will be a statistics also, With the following DBCC command, we can find the selectivity of a Statistics and there by the Index.

```
DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS('table name','statistics name')
```

It also displays, the Density, of the column when included with Clustered index columns. Lower selectivity will make optimizer ignore the index. We may find low performance query, even after creating index on the search column. The reason could be low selectivity.

```
Eg: 
SELECT sod.OrderQty ,
sod.SalesOrderID ,
sod.SalesOrderDetailID ,
sod.LineTotal
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod
WHERE sod.OrderQty = 10;
```

When a where condition is involved, the chances for a seek is high.But in the above query, the execution plan is showing a clustered index Scan. created a non clusterd index on OrderQty, still optimizer is ignoring the index. The reason is, Order quantity density is 1/41 distinct values = ~.25, With such a low selectivity, the optmizser finds it comparable with index scan itself.

Outdated STATISTICS could really make OPTIMIZER ignore the index.

There are different things that a DBA can do to help optimizer find the best execution plan. One amoung those are QUERY HINTS. Introducing Query hits could help, at the same time could be affect the performance, as well. An Index related Query hint is `WITH(INDEX())` 
We can tell optimizer to use a specific index.

```
    eg: SELECT * FROM table WITH (INDEX (0))            -- Can give index number
        SELECT * FROM table WITH (INDEX (indexName))    --
```

These things may help You